# Login system using service base database

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create a login system using service base database in ms studio,this form can create username and password. My problem is in comparing the username and password. When I type the username & password correctly it's fine, but when I type it incorrectly I'm having an error. Also, what if I created a multiple account, how can I compare the username & password in that particular account?

Here's what I've done so far:

where U add data:

```
Database1Entities1 dbentities1 = new Database1Entities1();
LogIn l1 = new LogIn();
l1.UserName = txtusername.Text;
l1.Password = txtpassword.Text;
dbentities1.LogIns.AddObject(l1);
dbentities1.SaveChanges();

MessageBox.Show("Account Save", "Account", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Here's what I've done to compare it:

```
Database1Entities1 db1entity = new Database1Entities1();
var loginsystem = (from p in db1entity.LogIns
                   where p.UserName == txtUserName.Text
                         && p.Password == txtPassword.Text
                   select p).FirstOrDefault();

if (txtUserName.Text == loginsystem.UserName
    && txtPassword.Text == loginsystem.Password)
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Welcome to your Record",
        "RMS",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information); 

else
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Sorry you type incorrect username/password",
        "Try Again",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "having an error"? ***Which*** error? Probably `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the 'FirstOrDefault()', add a null check and a 'loginsystem.count() > 0' to validate the user credentials.

Comment: im having an error if i remove the FirstOrDefault(); and also how/where can i add that loginsystem.count();